# Construct a mysql query and/or php code to associate ambiguous data points

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm not sure if what I'm asking for is a specific query or php code that will solve this, perhaps maybe what I'm asking for is an application. I'll do my best to explain the situation.

Imagine a series of real-world physical components and the network they form when they're connected together. Each component has two `Terminal`s, these terminals connect with `Node`s, and conceptually we can see below a small portion of the network's connectivity:

```
Object1 100000051
        100000052

Node1   400000051

Object2 100000053
        100000054

Node2   400000052
```

In this example, `Terminal` 2 of `Object1` is connected to `Node1`, and likewise `Terminal` 1 of `Object2` is connected to `Node1`. The goal of this query/php is to describe this connectivity.

A sample of data from the db:

```
Object table:
ObjectID(PK)   TerminalID1   TerminalID2
200000011      100000051    100000052

Node table:
NodeID(PK)
400000051

Terminal table:
TerminalID(PK)   NodeID
100000052      400000051
```

If I want to describe connectivity, I have to examine the connections in the data, so far I have:

Each `Object` has two `Terminal`s

Each `Terminal` has an associated `Node` ID

If I wanted to go down a line with hundreds of similar pieces of data, I would want a way to pull every node, then each component attached to that node. I feel like I'm missing something here, either conceptually or in the way my schema exists. Is there even a way to do this given the right schema? Do I need to just pull all the data, then create an algorithm to assemble it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a starting object ID, you can get the IDs it connects to with:

```
SELECT t.NodeID neighbor
FROM Object AS o
JOIN Terminal AS t ON t.TerminalID = o.TerminalID1
WHERE o.ObjectID = <starting ID>
UNION
SELECT t.NodeID neighbor
FROM Object AS o
JOIN Terminal AS t ON t.TerminalID = o.TerminalID2
WHERE o.ObjectID = <starting ID>
```

If you want to get the full network of all connected nodes, you'll have to perform this iteratively, using the IDs retrieved previously. Make sure you check for duplicates, or you'll end up looping infinitely if there are cycles.

Comment: Quick question here...does this depend on either the Object, Node, or Terminal IDs being in any kind of order? I ask because the IDs in some instances are not in order, and just scattered.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Terminal.NodeID, Object.ObjectID, Object.TerminalID1, Object.TerminalID2
 FROM Terminal
 INNER JOIN Object
 ON Terminal.TerminalID=Object.TerminalID2
```

This should get you what your looking for.
I'm not entirely sure of how it would react with duplicates so you might want to add a Distinct but i think it's a simple way to get it done

Comment: I'll ask you the same, so...does this depend on either the Object, Node, or Terminal IDs being in any kind of order? I ask because the IDs in some instances are not in order, and just scattered.

Comment: No, ordering is not required
As long as there is a row in Terminal with the terminal's ID and the  corresponding Node's ID, everything will work